# Do I need to apply for a Mexico visa before I apply for a Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, paperwork, schengen-visas, mexico

I am planning to travel to Mexico during my stay in Switzerland, which will last 45 days. During this time, I plan to travel to Mexico for 15 days. Do I need to apply for a Mexico visa in this case, as Mexico has visa on arrival for Schengen visa holders, but the [Schengen checklist](https://visa.vfsglobal.com/one-pager/switzerland/thailand/english/pdf/tourist-english-nov-2021.pdf) states the following:

> If the applicant continues to travel to a third country (i.e. UK, USA, Canada etc...) after leaving the Schengen Area, the visa of the next country has to be obtained first.

Comment: Can you give us a link to where you found that statement?

Comment: @DJClayworth : 
https://visa.vfsglobal.com/one-pager/switzerland/india/english/pdf/checklist-tourist.pdf

Comment: It's most likely that, before issuing you a Swiss visa, the Swiss authorities want to make sure that you'll be able to enter your next destination. What is your country of citizenship?

Comment: How long are you planning to stay in Switzerland before going to Mexico?  How long are you planning to stay there after going to Mexico?  What is the purpose of your trip?

Comment: Typically for a multi-country trip you would apply for your visa(s) in reverse order, starting with your final destination and working backwards through your itinerary. It sounds like you want to leverage holding a Schengen visa in order to be able to enter Mexico? In which case, you would need a multiple entry Schengen visa, but if you’re planning to spend some time in Switzerland *before* your trip to Mexico *and* you want to return to Switzerland for another stay after visiting Mexico, I don’t see why you’d need to get a Mexican visa *before* your Schengen visa.

Comment: @Traveller The OP's ID page shows they're from India. Indian citizens need a visa to enter Mexico. Thus. one would apply for the Mexican visa first, because having a Mexican visa demonstrates the OP's ability to enter Mexico, and justifies the multiple-entry nature of the Schengen visa that will be required for the OP's itinerary. Otherwise, the OP is apt to get a single-entry Schengen visa, with which they won't be able to re-enter Switzerland on the way home.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica Holding a valid Schengen visa exempts visitors from presenting a Mexican visa, regardless of their nationality https://consulmex.sre.gob.mx/toronto/index.php/en/servicesforeigners/doclegalization/52-conservices/225-visitors-who-do-not-require-a-visa-with-a-stay-up-to-180-days

Comment: @Traveller Yes, that's clear enough. But if the OP has only a single-entry Schengen visa, how will they get back into Switzerland for the second entry? And without a Mexican visa, how will they secure a multi-entry visa for the Schengen area in the first place?

Comment: @phoog I am planning to be in Switzerland 14 days before and 14 days after Mexico

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica Because the OP will apply for a multiple entry visa and provide a rationale and itinerary for Schengen, mentioning the Mexico trip in the middle?Maybe I’m missing something, but I have friends with knowledge of the Mexican visa exemption who have told me it works. No personal experience though. If there’s nothing explicit in the Schengen Code perhaps the OP should get advice from an immigration lawyer to be on the safe side